# SQL Server why there is still Key Lookup when index already covered all columns?

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, stored-procedures

I am running a SP which contains a query similar to below:

```
 DECLARE my_cursor CURSOR FOR 
 SELECT TOP 5000 id
 FROM Table
 WHERE ColA= 1 AND ColB= ColC
```

I created a non-clustered index where id is the index key column and include ColA,ColB and ColC.

Now, when I run the above query (w/o the cursor line) alone I can see that only Index Scan (using the index I created) is performed. This is good and as expected.

However, when I run the SP and look at the execution plan I am surprised to see that for the query above it does an Index Scan and a Key lookup (which takes a significant amount of time as well).

My understanding is that Key lookup will only come into play if there is some extra columns I have not covered in the index are needed. But obviously I have included all the necessary columns already.

Does anyone have an explanation of this? Thanks!

Comment: What version of SQL Server are you running?

Comment: I recreated your exact example in SQL 2012 and it only runs a Index Scan for me. What are the column types being compared in ColB and ColC?

Comment: ColA is tinyint, ColB and ColC are int.  id is a bigint and PK of Table.

Comment: When you right click on the Key Lookup and hit Properties, what's in the Output List of the Key Lookup?

Comment: The output list says Chk1002.

Comment: Can you post a repro with an actual query plan?

Comment: @Ben Thui, thx for looking into this problem. I have edited teh question accordingly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The underlying issue is you are using a cursor with the incorrect options.

When you declare a cursor using the default

```
DECLARE CURSOR crsr for SELECT * FROM TABLE
```

syntax, SQL Server creates a temporary table in tempdb with checksums of all the rows (or timestamps if the dataset contains a timestamp column) returned by that query. This is specified by the [OPTIMISTIC option](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa258831(v=sql.80).aspx), which is the default for cursors not defined with the `STATIC` or `FAST_FORWARD` options.

As you `FETCH NEXT` through the cursor, it compares the currently fetched row's checksum with the checksum stored in tempdb. If the checksums are different, it means the row itself was changed by the cursor, which is invalid, and that update is rejected.

If you don't plan on modifying the data contained within the cursor's query result (i.e. no changes to TABLE), then set the `FAST_FORWARD` option on your cursor and it will not perform this additional checksum step.

Ultimately, of course, the solution is to avoid cursors as they are a poor performer due to their reliance on temporary tables and synchronous data access.

Comment: Hmm... this appears to be an answer for a different question. Is that correct?

Comment: No, we had a chat and that was the underlying issue.

Comment: Ah, okay. As it stands right now, though, there's no obvious connection between the original question and your answer. Perhaps the OP could edit their question to at least include a reference to the cursor so as to be useful to others in the future. But you have no control over what s/he does. :)

Comment: @Ben Thui, thx for looking into this problem. I have edited teh question accordingly.

Comment: @Kyle Hale, Thx very much for your help. I have done some readings and try out some tricks, including your suggestion on FAST_FORWARD...and it works! It's now using index seek only in the execution plan.

I have also come across the INSENSITIVE cursor and it looks like it will do the trick as well, except that it is not as efficient as FAST_FORWARD, which is as expected. May I ask if FAST_FORWARD, which is a READ_ONLY, is by default a variant of INSENSITIVE ?

Comment: @xcoder No, INSENSITIVE is a different thing entirely; it actually copies the resultset of the cursor's query to tempdb and does all its FETCH operations (and modifications of the data, if any) on the temporary table - thus the original data is "insensitive" ie unable to be changed, but you can still make write operations on the temporary table's data within the cursor. As you noted, FAST_FORWARD is READ_ONLY - no modifications allowed whatsoever to the cursor data.

Comment: @xcoder Also, INSENSITIVE is the "old" way of doing things (it's from Sybase!) FAST_FORWARD is the "new" way  of doing the same thing.

Comment: Thanks for the info. I have just noticed something: as you can see I am processing in a batch of X every time this SP is called. I realised that the processing time for each SP (to finish the jobs in the batch of X) is gradually increasing. Is this due to the fact the the Cursor keeps filling up the memory and increase the garbage collection-like action?

Comment: FYI, I have made the above another question:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26914033/sql-server-multiple-calls-to-the-same-stored-procedure-affects-performance