# SQL Server Multiple calls to the same Stored Procedure affects performance?

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

I have a SP similar to below:

```
DECLARE my_cursor CURSOR FAST_FORWARD FOR 
SELECT TOP 500 id
FROM Table
WHERE colA= 1 AND colB= colC
--call another SP
--some other select/update operations
-- deallocate the cursor when everything is done
```

Now, say I have a Java program that calls this SP in a loop:

```
for (int i =0; i < 1000; i++)
     JPA.em().createNativeQuery("exec my_SP").executeUpdate(); //each time gets 500 to process
```

I realised that the processing time is gradually increasing. It takes only a few sec to finish the first loop, but quickly gone up to around a minute for a loop to finish.

I am guessing this is due to a shortage of memory as each loop the SP/cursor is occupying some of the memory space. So, eventually SQL Server needs to reclaim some of the memory and this becomes more frequent as the loop moves on (hence taking longer processing time).

I have two questions:

1. If the above is correct, why shouldn't the increased time be quite stable after certain point? Every time I am dealing with a constant number (500) of records. So, I thought, in terms of the memory, it is like 500 out and 500 in.
2. If the above is incorrect, why is the processing time increasing in each loop?
3. Is cursor is the main reason, or it is because I separate the SP calls into, say in this case, a thousand pieces?

Comment: yucky yucky cursors!

Comment: Agree...but I really want to know whether cursor is the reason. Or it is because I separate the SP calls into, say in this case, a thousand pieces?

Comment: Your problem is not related with Java at all.

Comment: Both...you are using a loop to call a stored proc which in turn uses a loop.

Comment: @ Luiggi. Thanks for eliminating that, I added the tag just in case it does...I cant be sure.

Comment: @SeanLange How separating the call pull down the performance?

Comment: You need to eliminate the cursor in your procedure. Would be even better if you can eliminate the need for looping to call it over and over. Without more to work with it is hard to know the best approach to get rid of your cursor.

Comment: I understand that's the best thing to do. But I really wanna understand which is the main reason and why separating SP calls can affect the performance.

Comment: Some of us have a natural inclination to blame the cursor.  This is easily tested.  Modify the stored procedure (for testing purposes) and remove the cursor.  Also, modify the stored procedure and remove the call to the other stored procedure.  If I had to guess, the performance issue is in the second stored procedure.

Answer (score 0):

I believe your issue is related to database locking.

You are firing off many threads of the same query all of which are getting in each others' way. SQL Server applies a read lock to prevent phantom reads but the main lock would be your update statements that would need a write lock. Other threads have to wait until it is released before they can continue, so a backlog of waiting threads form otherwise know as Db blocking.

You can experiment by commenting out the SQL update statements and you may also need to add the following line at the top of your script for testing purposes:

```
SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL READ UNCOMMITTED
```

You should find things to speed up.